# strange splash screen problem in iphone native application?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

i have a application i put Default.png for splash screen according to apple's documentation.the splash screen is displaying fine.but when i delete the Default.png and references of png.it does not removed it is still showing the splash screen.i am running the program in simulator.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution:

1. Stop any iPhone Simulation
2. In XCode click Build -> Clear in the menu bar
3. Uncheck both boxes and click "clean"
4. Rebuild your application.

Comment: this works in another project but in my project the problem still occurs.i tried this but this method doesn't work for me.i am unable add a new file named Default.png x-code gives an error.

Comment: Sorry if this is a bit late, but you still have a Default.png inside your project directory, you had only deleted the reference from the XCode project.